# UPlay Plus free month: What happens if I cancel now?

Tags: ubisoft-connect

I activated my free trial of UPlay+ yesterday, and successfully downloaded some games. If not cancelled at the latest at the end of the month (September 30th), I will be charged 14,99€ / month from there on by Ubisoft, according to them.

If I cancel right now, how will it affect the running free trial? Will there be any penalties / limitations to what I can do with UPlay+ or the games I downloaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cancel the trial now, the trial will continue until the end date and then terminate. Upon the terminations, games downloaded via UPlay+ will cease working and do nothing but take space in your hard drive.

It basically functions the same as any other subscription based system. However, if you *do* buy a game, that game will remain with you even after the subscription ends. This means you actually bought the game via store, rather than gained access through subscription.

Source:

1. https://support.ubi.com/en-GB/faqs/000045736
2. https://support.ubi.com/en-GB/faqs/45739/Information-about-the-Uplay-free-trial/

Comment: Presumably games you already own will still be playable after your UPlay+ subscription ends. Also https://support.ubi.com/en-GB/faqs/45739/Information-about-the-Uplay-free-trial/

Comment: @DavidYell I surely hope so..

Comment: Yes, games you actually own (either buying through store or activating keys) will remain with you even after the subscription ends. I have updated the answer to reflect this.